# PDO login - add user level to session

Tags: php, pdo

i need to add user level from database when he log in, unforunately i am doing it wrong because its not working at all. My code looks like:

```
 public $username = null;
 public $password = null;
 public $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";

 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
     if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
 }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
    //store the parameters
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }
```

And function for login

```
 public function userLogin() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 90";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['level'] = $rows[0]['userID'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = "6";
        if( $valid ) {
            $success = true;
        }
        $con = null;
        return $success;
     }catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         return $success;
     }
 }
```

**Sumary**:
*What i need:* When user log in it get his level from database table and add it to $_SESSION['level'] 
*What error i get:* I get no error at all, session level is blanked
*Where is a problem:* To say true i have no idea, not getting any error, so i dont know what i am doing wrong so i hope for some advises or explanations

```
print_r of my $_SESSION:

Array ( [username] => michal [id] => 6 [loggedin] => 1 [level] => )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing a session you should first start it:

[session_start();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

You should use `fetch()` because it is a single row.

```
$stmt->execute();

if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
    $_SESSION['level'] = $row['userID'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = "6";
    return true;
}
```

---

```
 public function userLogin() {
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 90";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
            $_SESSION['level'] = $row['userID'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = "6";
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        $con = null;
        return $success;
     }catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your code works well mate, but can you explain me a bit more what i did wrong and why it didnt work? If i understand it i will not come to this situation again

Comment: oh you forgot to start the session `session_start();` I will edit my answer

Comment: nope i didnt forgot start a session, just didnt display it. Diffence is in that fetch imo

Comment: I removed `$stmt->fetchColumn();` as well , you dont want to fetch twice